# Django: Q Objects concatenation

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter

Been trying to filter with Q Objects and be able to search for "Firstname" + "Lastname", but only able to search for one or the other. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Evaluation search view**

For clarification:

ma = employee number

fornavn = firstname

efternavn = lastname

fagnavn = subject name

aktivitetnavn = aktivity name

vuderingsnavn = grade

delingnavn = department (integer)

```
class SearchEvalueringer(ListView):
    model = Evaluering
    template_name = 'evalsys/categories/søg_evalueringer.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if len(query) > 1:
            eval_list = Evaluering.objects.filter(
                Q(ma__ma__regex=query) |
                Q(ma__fornavn__iregex=query) |
                Q(ma__efternavn__iregex=query) |
                Q(fagnavn__fagnavn__iregex=query) |
                Q(aktivitetnavn__aktivitetnavn__iregex=query) |
                Q(vuderingsnavn__vuderingsnavn__iregex=query) |
                Q(ma__holdnavn__holdnavn__iregex=query)
            )
        else:
            eval_list = Evaluering.objects.filter(
                Q(ma__delingnavn__delingnavn__exact=query)
            )
        return eval_list
```

I tried doing this:

```
Q(ma__fornavn__iregex=query) & Q(ma__efternavn__iregex=query)
```

But this does not let me search for "John Smith" still only "John" or "Smith".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, where you annotate full_name onto the queryset by concating first and last name, and filter on that.

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

queryset.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat(
        "first_name", Value(" "), "last_name", 
        output_filed=CharField()
    ).filter(
        full_name=query
    )
```